# SQL Server --> Informix DB Linked Server

Tags: sql-server, sql-server-2016, linked-server, informix

After about 3 days of trying, I am unable to create a linked server from SQL Server 2016 to Informix 11.5. I haven't tried this with other versions (2008R2, etc) since I wanted to set up the connection in a test environment first.

**What I have Done**

- Installed [the latest Informix OLE DB Driver](https://www-01.ibm.com/marketing/iwm/tnd/search.jsp?rs=ifxdl) on the SQL Server host machine
- Configured a [System DSN for the IBM Informix ODBC Driver Setup](https://amrgaber.wordpress.com/2011/02/24/create-an-odbc-connection-to-connect-to-cisco-uccx-server/)
- Tested the connectivity of the DSN settings (test is good) after [changing the locale settings](https://www.ibm.com/developerworks/community/blogs/gbowerman/entry/trouble_with_locales?lang=en) so the client and server match, and server is correct.
- Attempted to create the linked server in two ways below.
- Googled and read everything I could to resolve this without success.

1) Using IBM Informix [instructions with OLE DB Provider](http://www-01.ibm.com/support/docview.wss?uid=swg21195578) in which I get the following error (regardless if I use a DNS in provider string):

> Cannot initialize the data source object of OLE DB provider "Ifxoledbc" for linked server "UCCX". OLE DB provider "Ifxoledbc"  for linked server "UCCX" returned messazge "EIX000: (-23197)" Database locale information mismatch" (Microsoft SQL Server, Error: 7303)

*The DB Locale is en_US.57372*

2) Using Microsoft OLE DB Provider for SQL Server [as explained in this blog](https://sqlcindy.blogspot.com/2014/06/query-ccx-informix-from-ssms.html?showComment=1492183909296#c9217368591677318228) which returns the error:

> Named Pipes Provider: Coould not open a connection to SQL Server. OLE DB provider SQLNCLI11 for linked server UCCX returned message "Login timeout expired"
>   OLE DB provider SQLNCLI11 for linked server UCCX retunred a message "A network-related or instance-specific error has occured while establishing a connection to SQL Server. Server is not found or not accessible. Check if instance name is correct and if SQL Server is configured to allow remote connections. SQLNCLI11 for linked server UCCX returned message "Invalid connection string attribute"

I have very little experience with Informix which should be apparent and this isn't a local installation, it's a Cisco instance as you probably gleaned from the blogs I was using. Any advice would be appreciated.

Comment: For Issue #1, what bit-level of the drivers did you install and what bit-level of SQL Server are you running?  These two should be the same.  For #2, you can't use the SQL Native Client to connect to an Informix database.  That blog is misleading as I suspect the author is using the Informix drivers installed in step #1 of her instructions.

Comment: @JohnEisbrener 64 bit for both. I saw where a lot of people had problems installing 32-bit drivers and getting them to work. I thought it was fishy as well but she posted an image AND put the text with that provider. If she would have chosen the Informix driver the catalog would have been grayed out.

Comment: Can you see the recently installed Informix driver under `ServerName -> Server Objects -> Linked Servers -> Providers`?  If you cannot see the provider, you may need to restart the instance.  Alternatively, you may have an odd driver install that is user-specific and not server wide, in which case you may need to install it _as_ the same user running SQL.

Comment: @JohnEisbrener I do see the driver when connected as myself (an admin) and connected as another local admin account.

Comment: I hope [this](http://www-01.ibm.com/support/docview.wss?uid=swg21639004) is not your issue, as the workaround looks plain awful.  I don't think your Linked Server is misconfigured, but maybe passing `Client_Locale=en_us.8859-1` in the connection string (via [ConnectionStrings.com](https://www.connectionstrings.com/luxena-dbexpress-driver-for-informix-pro/)) would work?  I'm grasping at straws on this though... sorry

Comment: Interesting article, though it shouldn't be the case since only one application is inserting into the DB and the only thing that has ever connected to it. I did try the full string, though using the dsn should have eliminated this. Seems like IBm doesn't want you using MS to connect!

Comment: Can you connect anything else via OLE? Excel? Access? How did you test the connectivity?

Comment: @Peter we only have the single Informix instance so I haven't gotten anything connected through this driver, though when i set up the DSN for this driver in the ODBC driver the test connection is successful. I can use the MS OLE driver for excel and have half a dozen other MS Linked servers from this SQL Server instance as well. as John commented, I wouldn't expect the MS OLE for SQL Server to actually work, but tried it since the blog said it would work.

Comment: I would try to use another tool to select data. Such as msaccess. It will help to identify if the problem is on the informix or sql side of the dsn. I wouldnt rely on just the "test". Prove the dsn and driver work.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

We had a nightmare setting something similar up, specifically with the issue of connecting to multiple Informix environments. I had several Informix instances that needed to be linked to a single SQL Server instance for warehousing purposes, and was told by our resident SME that this was impossible; only a single Informix instance could be referenced per server.

I would consistently receive the same errors as you, and nothing I was able to dredge up online proved helpful.

Ultimately, the solution had several parts, of which you've done the first few:

1. The correct `IBM Informix ODBC Driver` must be installed on the database server.
2. Use the SetNet32 application provided with the drivers and set up the Server Information tab appropriately. Additionally, set up a corresponding System DSN entry.
3. The trick with the Linked Server setup is to use the following (items in codeblocks are literal):

   - Provider: `Microsoft OLE DB Provider for ODBC Drivers`
   - Product Name: `Ifxoledbc`
   - Data Source: **$YourSystemDSNName**
   - Provider String

     - Driver = `{IBM INFORMIX ODBC DRIVER}`
     - Database = **$YourDatabaseName**
     - etc...

If you're more of a manual SQL kind of person, see below. The provider string is pulled into a variable for inline commenting purposes only, while still having executable code. Modify as needed:

```
DECLARE @provider NVARCHAR(4000);
SET @provider = N'Driver={IBM INFORMIX ODBC DRIVER};'
  + N'DATABASE= ;'  --Informix DB name
  + N'HOST= ;'      --Informix Hostname or IP adddress
  + N'SERVICE= ;'   --Informix service name, ex.  ifx1_tcp1
  + N'PROTOCOL= ;'  --Informix protocol, ex.  onsoctcp
  + N'SERVER= ;'    --Informix server, ex. ifx1
  + N'DB_LOCALE=en_US.819; CLIENT_LOCALE=en_US.819;'; --Change to your locale, as needed

EXEC master.dbo.sp_addlinkedserver 
@server = N'UCCX', --Linked Server system name
@srvproduct=N'Ifxoledbc', 
@provider=N'MSDASQL', 
@datasrc=N' ', --Your System DSN Name
@provstr= @provider;
```

Since you're dealing with a single instance, it should be enough to simply match the values used to create your System DSN. If you need to add additional linked servers for other instances, that can be done following exactly the same format described above without additional DSN entries.

I hope that helps.

Comment: A portion of that is from memory, so if you encounter any issues, let me know and we can work on it together.