# Informix DB export to Microsoft SQL Server 2016

Tags: sql-server, export, informix

I have an Informix Database and a Microsoft SQL Server 2016. 
My task is to dump the whole Informix Database and export it to the Microsoft SQL Server Database. 
I installed the Informix SDK 4.5. I also have installed the ODBC drivers 32bit/64bit. The connection is working fine.

[image: ODBC drivers]

I linked the Informix Server within the `Microsoft SQL Server Management Studio`, but i was not able to get table information, so i found a workaround in IBMs Documentation.

[image: Linked Informix Server]

Now I wantet to try an export with `Import and Export Data (64-bit)`. I chose the data source as `IBM Informix OLE DB Provider`

Data Destination is `SQL Server Native Client 11.0`

As a test export i choose some tables. The table Mapping looks fine for me

The next step shows the Type Conversion with an error, but i dont know why.

Then I `Run immediatly`

```
[Source Information]
Source Location : sospos@sosposdbtest
Source Provider : Ifxoledbc.4
Cannot locate the mapping file to map the provider types to SSIS types
```

After that I get errors and warnings.

Warning:

```
Could not connect source component. Warning 0x80202066: Source - auswahl_hoefken [1]: Cannot retrieve the column code page info from the OLE DB provider. If the component supports the "DefaultCodePage" property, the code page from that property will be used. Change the value of the property if the current string code page values are incorrect. If the component does not support the property, the code page from the component's locale ID will be used.
```

Error:

```
Error 0xc02020e8: Source 27 - antrzusatz [157]: Opening a rowset fo ""sospos":"sosgx"."antrzusatz"" failed. Check that the object exists in the database.
```

I get this Warnings for several tables..

I think there is a problem with the table mapping or something like that, but I'm not sure..

Any ideas?

Comment: Can you actually select from a table in informix from SSMS via your linked server?

Comment: If so, could you provide your Linked Server information or perhaps answer [this question](https://dba.stackexchange.com/questions/171204/sql-server-informix-db-linked-server)

Answer (score 0):

You might try and check if you can get data out of the Informix database via the linked server. 
If the direct query fails, you might have some luck with the use of OPENQUERY

```
SELECT * FROM OPENQUERY ([name of linked server], 'Query text')
```

If this works, maybe a select into gets the job done.